# How to filter array of object based on another array Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I have below sample data in **excelData** and **apiResponse**.

I want to filter excelData array based on apiResponse makeLineName.

**For Ex -** In apiResponse, we have below TestDemo1 and Test565 makeLineName available
So i want to search exceldata array for this TestDemo1 and Test565 makeLineName and if same name availalble in excelData
than filter the excelData array and remove this object from excelData array of object and provide the rest object in result.

```
const excelData = [
      {
        makeLineId: 25,
        makeLineName: "TestDemo1",
        makeProcessTypeId: 43
      },
      {
        makeLineId: 26,
        makeLineName: "Test565",
        makeProcessTypeId: 44
      },
      {
        makeLineId: 27,
        makeLineName: "Luck",
        makeProcessTypeId: 45
      }
    ];

    const apiResponse = [
      {
        makeLineId: 25,
        makeLineName: "TestDemo1",
        makeProcessTypeId: 43
      },
      {
        makeLineId: 26,
        makeLineName: "Test565",
        makeProcessTypeId: 44
      }
    ];
```

**Expected output**

```
const excelData = [      
      {
        makeLineId: 27,
        makeLineName: "Luck",
        makeProcessTypeId: 45
      }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Array.map and Array.filter

You can look through the apiResponse to get each element. Here I have used [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through apiResponse.

Then you can filter the data in excelData using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that returns the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
let excelData = [ { makeLineId: 25, makeLineName: "TestDemo1", makeProcessTypeId: 43 }, { makeLineId: 26, makeLineName: "Test565", makeProcessTypeId: 44 }, { makeLineId: 27, makeLineName: "Luck", makeProcessTypeId: 45 } ];
const apiResponse = [ { makeLineId: 25, makeLineName: "TestDemo1", makeProcessTypeId: 43 }, { makeLineId: 26, makeLineName: "Test565", makeProcessTypeId: 44 } ];


const filteredData=excelData.filter(x=>!apiResponse.find(e=>e.makeLineId==x.makeLineId))

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Can you plz suggest how we assign whole result to a new variable for ex i want like below  - const filteredData = apiResponse.map(item => {
  excelData = excelData.filter(data => data.makeLineName != item.makeLineName);

});

Comment: Can you plz suggest how we assign whole result to a new variable for ex i want like below - const filteredData = apiResponse.map(item => { excelData = excelData.filter(data => data.makeLineName != item.makeLineName); });

Comment: @LEXTRA33, to loop over an array use forEach, not map., Pravesh you can use filter and find in the way `filteredDat=apiResponse.filter(x=>!excelData.find(e=>e.makeLineId==x.makeLineId))`

Comment: PraveshSingh As pointed out by @Eliseo you can filter out using find and use the id to compare instead of the name as its a more reliable and ideal comparison. Updated my answer. Thanks Eliseo.